# Сложные слова с «видео» и «аудио» — слитно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, морфология

Часто в поисковиках (даже российском Яндексе) встречаются разные способы написания сложнокоренных слов, начинающихся с "аудио-" или "видео-", когда **второй корень начинается на гласную**.

И всё же, как правильно писать: "видеоигры" или "видео-игры", "аудио-урок" или "аудиоурок"?

Comment: Например, в орфографическом словаре за 2009 год дается слитное написание всех слов с с "аудио-" или "видео-", в том числе перед гласной: видеоархив, видеоадаптер.Также слитно пишется "видеоигра" в Русском орфографическом словаре под ред. Лопатина.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написание сложных слов с "аудио-" или "видео-" в первой части всегда было слитным, и современные правила не изменились: это подтверждает сайт Грамота.ру, который в наибольшей степени близок к современной официальной орфографии.

Однако в Интернете можно встретить и раздельное, и дефисное написание слов. Это можно объяснить расширением области значений этих слов, которые могут являться  самостоятельными существительными и в этом статусе претендовать роль приложения с дефисным написанием или на роль несогласованного определения в препозиции.

Comment: Портал "Грамота.ру" держу в закладках и регулярно пользуюсь его материалами, но... он же не единственный.)

Можно увидеть конкретные примеры — **когда именно** пишется слитно и когда с дефисом?

Мне кажется, какую-то роль здесь играет последовательность из трёх (и более) гласных подряд...

Comment: Раздельное и дефисное написание в настоящее время не является нормативным, официально так писать нельзя.